# Updating Pandas dataframe with "new information" when it includes NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

### Updating Pandas dataframe with "new information"

What I'd like to do is build a function that does the following (pseudo code):

```
def update(original_information, new_information):
    ... stuff ...
    return updated_information
```

Both the inputs and the output above are Pandas dataframes, all of which can contain a number of NaNs.

an example of **original_information**:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['edgar', 'morningstar', 'yahoo']
companies = [{'edgar': '0000320193', 'yahoo': 'AAPL'}, {'morningstar': 'XYZ', 'yahoo': 'SGO.PA'}]
original_information = pd.DataFrame(companies, columns=columns).sort_values('yahoo').reset_index(drop=True)

   edgar        morningstar  yahoo
0  00000320193  NaN          AAPL
1  NaN          XYZ          SGO.PA
```

an example of **new information**:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['edgar', 'morningstar', 'yahoo']
companies = [{'morningstar': 'AAPL', 'yahoo': 'AAPL'}, {'morningstar': 'XPAR:SGO', 'yahoo': 'SGO.PA'}]
new_information = pd.DataFrame(companies, columns=columns).sort_values('yahoo').reset_index(drop=True)

   edgar  morningstar  yahoo
0  NaN    AAPL         AAPL
1  NaN    XPAR:SGO     SGO.PA
```

Ideally my **update** function would accomplish three things:

1. In cell (1, morningstar), update 'XYZ' with 'XPAR:SGO' since 'XPAR:SGO' is newer information
2. In cell (0, morningstar), show 'AAPL' since the original information was 'NaN'
3. In cell (0, edgar), keep '000320192' because there is no new information for that cell

In other words, what I'd like **updated_information** to look like is the following:

```
   edgar        morningstar  yahoo
0  00000320193  AAPL         AAPL
1  NaN          XPAR:SGO     SGO.PA
```

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this yet

What I have is the following:

```
def update(original_information, new_information):
    result = pd.concat([original_information, new_information], ignore_index=True)
    result = result.drop_duplicates(subset='yahoo', keep='last').sort_values('yahoo').reset_index(drop=True)
    return result
```

which returns:

```
   edgar  morningstar  yahoo
0  NaN    AAPL         AAPL
1  NaN    XPAR:SGO     SGO.PA
```

which...

1. successfully replaces 'XYZ' with 'XPAR:SGO' in cell (1, morningstar)
2. successfully updates cell (0, morningstar) with 'AAPL'
3. **but unfortunately** deletes '000320192' in cell (0, edgar) instead of keeping it

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well specified question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use [`.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), as it only uses non-NA values from the new data when doing the update.

```
original_information.update(new_information)
```

Comment: Such an easy answer! And it seems to work. I definitely feel stupid now, but thanks for the help!

Comment: OK.  That didn't quite work for me as I started coming up with other examples.  I have a new question that, if I can find an answer to it, would solve all my problems.

Comment: Here it is (if I can manage to write it correctly in a comment):

Comment: Nevermind.  Think I just solved it.  In any case, thanks!

Comment: I'll post a more general answer to the problem when I figure everything out.